# Async function doesn't wait with await before returning

Tags: javascript, async-await

Consider the following code:

```js
const getName = () => 
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'xxx'));

f = async () => {
  let name = await getName();
  console.log(name);
  return name;
}

console.log(f());
```

The function will wait before printing "name" but it will still return the promise instead of the result and won't print the correct output outside the function. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You are not awaiting f()

Comment: getName is not returning anything

Comment: @Nonik It is, an arrow function without curly brackets implicitly returns the expression.

Comment: *"but it will still return the promise instead of the result"* - Async functions always return a Promise, they never directly return the "result".  It's up to the consumer (where the function is invoked) to await that promise.

Comment: If your goal is to wait for `f()` to finish outside of an `async` function, then I'm afraid that is not possible.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `await` for `f()`. Here is an example:

```js
const getName = () => 
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'xxx'));

const f = async () => {
  const name = await getName();
  console.log("1. "+name);
  return name;
}

const run = (async () => {
  const ret = await f();
  console.log("2. "+ret);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to await the promise returned by the f function.  That is why its printing a promise instead of a result.

```
console.log(await f());
```

Comment: That doesn't compile

Comment: @GeneralGravicius: If this is at the top level (outside an `async` function) then you'd do something like: `f().then(x => console.log(x));`  The `await` keyword doesn't work outside of an async function, so you'd use callback syntax instead.  (Or wrap it in an async IIFE.)

Comment: @David thanks I ended up using an async IIFE